# What is the running time and space complexity of a huffman decode algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code, big-o

Say we started with a text file like:

```
a 00 
b 01
c 10
d 11

00000001011011
```

The algorithm would be the typical one where you use the prefixes to build a Huffman tree, read in the encoded bits while traversing the tree until you reach a leaf, then returning the character in at that leaf.

Could someone explain how I would determine the running time and space complexity?

Comment: what does the wiki page say?

Comment: You've described an algorithm to do this, but do you have code as well?  The time complexity may vary depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically there are three methods on a Huffman Tree, construction, encoding, and decoding. The time complexity may vary from each other.

We should first notice that (see Wikipedia [[link]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)):

> In many cases, time complexity is not very important in the choice of algorithm here, since n here is the number of symbols in the alphabet, which is typically a very small number (compared to the length of the message to be encoded); whereas complexity analysis concerns the behavior when n grows to be very large.

1. The complexity of construction is linear (O(n)) if input probabilities are sorted, see this [paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#cite_note-1). In most cases, we use a greedy O(n*log(n)) construction method: 
   http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html
2. If you build a bidirection hashtable for all symbols, both encoding and decoding would be constant (O(1)).

Answer (score 4):

Assume an encoded text string of length n and an alphabet of k symbols.

For every encoded symbol you have to traverse the tree in order to decode that symbol. The tree contains k nodes and, *on average*, it takes O(log k) node visits to decode a symbol. So the time complexity would be O(n log k).

Space complexity is O(k) for the tree and O(n) for the decoded text.

Comment: Why is the time complexity is O(k)? In the worst case the output tree could be a full binary tree having k+k\2+k\4+...+1=O(k^2) nodes.

Comment: @so.very.tired: Re-read my answer. I said that the *space* complexity is O(k). With k characters there are k nodes in the tree.

Comment: Sorry I've been meaning to ask: "Why is the space complexity is... etc...", I wrote "time" instead of "space" by mistake. 
In Huffman tree, letters are represented by *terminal* nodes (not just any node), so with k characters, there are k terminal nodes, which means the tree can, like I said, end up with O(k^2) nodes (terminal as well as internal).